# skip an element using next()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In here,

http://jsfiddle.net/sjKgF/78/

JS CODE

```
$('.display_box').hover(function (){            
    $(this).attr('class', 'display_box current')
}, function (){
    $(this).attr('class', 'display_box');
});


$('#search').keyup(
function (e){
    var curr = $('#display').find('.current');
    if (e.keyCode == 40) 
    {                                      
        if(curr.length)
        {
                $(curr).attr('class', 'display_box');
                $(curr).next().attr('class', 'display_box current');
        }
        else{
            $('#display div:first-child').attr('class', 'display_box current');
        }                    
    }
    if(e.keyCode==38)
    {                                        
        if(curr.length)
        {                            
                $(curr).attr('class', 'display_box');
                $(curr).prev().attr('class', 'display_box current');
        }
        else{
            $('#display div:last-child').attr('class', 'display_box current');
        }            
    }
}        
)​
```

ELEMTS

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search_fld"/>
<div id="display">
<div class="display_box current">Luca</div>
<div class="display_box">David</div>
<p class="other">Mark</p>
<div class="display_box">...</div>
</div>
```

​
How can i skip the `<p>` element and continue with only `<div>` ?

Thanks

Comment: Please include the code in the question, not just a link. What do you mean by "skip the... element?"

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL jsfiddle is the code in this case. It is even better than text code in fact

Comment: i included the code. i meant that i dont want <p> to get display_box current class here ->  $(curr).next().attr('class', 'display_box current');

Comment: @JustinPihony [au contraire, mon ami](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114942/when-jsfiddle-and-other-related-sites-are-gone-so-is-the-information)

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I thought you might go there :). Agreed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a selector to [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next):

```
$(curr).next('div').attr('class', 'display_box current');
```

---

> it doesnt work like that, i tried this. it doesnt continue to next DIV with text "..." if i do that

Okay, let my try my crystal ball again:

```
$(curr).nextAll('div').first().attr('class', 'display_box current');
```

Comment: and next time RTFD. The jQuery API docs have 95%+ of the answers.

Comment: it doesnt work like that, i tried this. it doesnt continue to next DIV with text "..." if i do that

Comment: If you read the doc yourself, you will see that `.next()` retrieves the very next sibling and if you pass a selector, it either returns the next sibling if it matches the selector or returns nothing.  It does not look for the next sibling that matches the selector.

Comment: @Ahmetvardar so what do you want - the next div, regardless of whether it is the next sibling or not? `.nextAll('div').first()`.

Comment: THX .nextAll('div').first() did it

Answer (score 1):

To find the next sibling that is a div regardless of whether it's the very next sibling, use this:

```
$(curr).nextAll("div").eq(0).attr('class', 'display_box current');
```

`.next()` only finds the very next sibling.

`.next(selector)` gets the next sibling, but only returns it if it matches the selector, otherwise, it returns an empty jQuery object.

So, if you want to find the next sibling that matches a selector regardless of whether it's the very next sibling or not, then you need to use `.nextAll(selector)` and, if you only want the first one, you can narrow it to the first one with `.eq(0)` or `.first()`.